# Fish Shell: "error: Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied"

Tags: fish

I am using the Fish shell (version 3.3.1) on MacOS.  Every time I run a command it shows this error multiple times:

```
error: Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied
```

The commands still run perfectly, but it's very annoying to see these errors.  They are still on the screen even after a `clear` command.

Comment: What does `fish --version` show?

Comment: fish, version 3.3.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  A quick heads-up that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question appears to be more about a *shell issue* and would likely be better suited for either the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com).  I would recommend deleting it here and reposting it on a more appropriate site. Thanks!

Comment: if you know how to reslove this error , pls help

Comment: My solution was to go through all the steps to uninstall fish. Then I changed the ownership of my .config directory:
`$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff ~/.config`
and finally installed it again with homebrew

Comment: If you install fish using `brew`. first, go to the directory `/Users/$USER/.config`, and change the ownership of this config file to the current user. just like @Phoenix666 said.

Comment: For those who have this problem with android studio, solve it with the command:

sudo chown user:usergrup -R /opt/android-studio/plugins/terminal/fish

You get the usergroup with the uid or id command

Comment: I fixed my new fish installation (which protested with the string in the title) using this single permissions change to the fish directory: `sudo chown -R <user> ~/.config/fish`. Check your current perms first.

Answer (score 5):

Fish has a feature where it'll store so called "universal" variables to a file on disk, so they can easily be persisted and shared among open fishes.

This error:

> error: Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied

Shows that fish is trying to open the file at "/", the root of the filesystem. This points to a misconfiguration, because "/" isn't a file, by definition. It's a directory.

The file is supposed to be in the config directory, which is at:

- $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish, if that variable is set
- $HOME/.config/fish, if it isn't

I can't find the specific sequence to reproduce this, but it appears that $XDG_CONFIG_HOME or $HOME are set when fish is started (by its parent process, probably the terminal), and to non-functional values.

Comment: so what should i suppose to do then?

Comment: You should check those variables, see what they are set to, and where the wrong value is coming from. That's somewhere outside of fish, in its parent process. Your terminal, tmux, your IDE (if you're using a terminal inside an IDE - IntelliJ has known bugs in its fish integration!). Then resolve that problem. Something is giving fish broken data and that data needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Was having this same issue after installing using `brew install fish`.

What finally worked was uninstalling fish.

```
brew uninstall fish
```

Then removing `fish` from my `.config` folder.

```
cd ~
rm -rf .config/fish
```

Then I just installed fish using the [fish GUI installer](https://fishshell.com/).